# What are relevant missions for CubeSats?

Tags: artificial-satellite, mission-design, cubesat, remote-sensing

My high school is planning to launch a CubeSat to the ISS, but we need a mission. A majority of students involved are interested in the engineering aspect of constructing it, and we don't know what it should accomplish once it's launched. 
I've been looking through [Wikipedia's page on launched CubeSats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CubeSats) and it seems most are focused on R&D or remote sensing. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Putting a camera on it to send pictures back to Earth would be a cool start.

Comment: Have you tried simply doing a web search for high school cubesat projects?  Do you want to look at this as a having a direct educational value or is it mainly to provide some focus for the platform "team". It may well help if you can build on links with a nearby university, though overall this is not a small commitment for students who are also trying to pass exams.